# Macbook Pro late 2011 version won´t boot up

Tags: hard-drive, startup, disk-utility

Hi guys I have been searching the forum and haven´t seen a solution to my problem therefore i will start by explaining what happened. Last night all of a sudden my mac froze, the mouse would move but i couldnt work minimise or close any programme. Neither could i turn it off or restart it. Therefore I decided to press and hold the power button. There after my macbook won't turn on all I see is the grey screen with the apple logo with a little fan like thing spinning at the bottom. I tried entering in recovery mode and verify the Hard drive on disc utility i get the following message:
*Invalid content in journal
Invalid record count
The volume could not be verified completely.
Error: The disk needs to be repaired. Click repair Disk.*

So I clicked on repair disk and I get the following message:
*Invalid content in journal
Invalid record cound
The volume could not be verified completely.
Invalid content in journal
Error: Disk Utility can´t repair this disk...disk, and restore your backed-up files*

Also a pop up box with the following:
Disk utility cant repair this disk. Back up as many of your files as possible, reformat the disk, and restore your backed up files.

As a note I see on disc utility when my internal HD is selected:
Mount Point: Not mounted
Format: Mac OS Extended (Journaled)

I have very important documents and other stuff which I havent had a chance to back up yet so it is important for me to recover these.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to recover some data from you hard drive, I think that the best option is to start your Mac with CMD + R.
You'll need an external Hard Drive. From Utility choose "Disk Utility" and format the extenal HD in Mac OS X Extended (Journaled) with GUID Partition option.
After that, quit Disk Utility and Choose "Restore Mac OS X" from the main menu.
Complete the installation on the external HD and boot your Mac while pressing Option key.
Choose the External HD, and it will boot up with the new system where you can try to access to your data from Macintosh HD.

Otherwise unplug your internal HD and connect to your computer with a SATA-USB adapter.